# need help converting a triangle in string to array

Tags: python, algorithm

```
triangle = """
75
95 64
17 47 82
18 35 87 10
20 04 82 47 65
19 01 23 75 03 34
88 02 77 73 07 63 67
99 65 04 28 06 16 70 92
41 41 26 56 83 40 80 70 33
41 48 72 33 47 32 37 16 94 29
53 71 44 65 25 43 91 52 97 51 14
70 11 33 28 77 73 17 78 39 68 17 57
91 71 52 38 17 14 91 43 58 50 27 29 48
63 66 04 68 89 53 67 30 73 16 69 87 40 31
04 62 98 27 23 09 70 98 73 93 38 53 60 04 23"""
```

```
def return_triangle(triangle,n):
    arr_start = triangle.split()
    print(arr_start)
    current_row = 1
    start_index = current_row - 1
    max_index = start_index + current_row
    triangle_array = []
    while current_row <= rows:
        print('len arr_start',len(arr_start))
        temp_arr = []
        for i in range(start_index,max_index):
            temp_arr.append(arr_start[i])
        triangle_array.append([temp_arr])
        current_row += 1
        start_index += current_row - 1
        max_index = start_index + current_row
    return triangle_array

print(return_triangle(triangle))

here is my output 
[['63', '66', '04', '68', '89', '53', '67', '30', '73', '16', '69', '87', '40', '31']]
12
[['91', '71', '52', '38', '17', '14', '91', '43', '58', '50', '27', '29', '48']]
11
[['70', '11', '33', '28', '77', '73', '17', '78', '39', '68', '17', '57']]
10
[['53', '71', '44', '65', '25', '43', '91', '52', '97', '51', '14']]
9
[['41', '48', '72', '33', '47', '32', '37', '16', '94', '29']]
8
[['41', '41', '26', '56', '83', '40', '80', '70', '33']]
7
[['99', '65', '04', '28', '06', '16', '70', '92']]
6
[['88', '02', '77', '73', '07', '63', '67']]
5
[['19', '01', '23', '75', '03', '34']]
4
[['20', '04', '82', '47', '65']]
3
[['18', '35', '87', '10']]
2
[['17', '47', '82']]
1
[['95', '64']]
0
[['75']]
0
```

i get up to the last n-2 rows
but i cannot get the last 2 rows to print i want to know how to do that withut going out of bound in my loop.
Now if i look at my expected output which is supposed to be

[[04, 62, 98, 27, 23, 09, 70, 98, 73, 93, 38, 53, 60, 04, 23]]
13
[['63', '66', '04', '68', '89', '53', '67', '30', '73', '16', '69', '87', '40', '31']]
12
[['91', '71', '52', '38', '17', '14', '91', '43', '58', '50', '27', '29', '48']]
11
[['70', '11', '33', '28', '77', '73', '17', '78', '39', '68', '17', '57']]
10
[['53', '71', '44', '65', '25', '43', '91', '52', '97', '51', '14']]
9
[['41', '48', '72', '33', '47', '32', '37', '16', '94', '29']]
8
[['41', '41', '26', '56', '83', '40', '80', '70', '33']]
7
[['99', '65', '04', '28', '06', '16', '70', '92']]
6
[['88', '02', '77', '73', '07', '63', '67']]
5
[['19', '01', '23', '75', '03', '34']]
4
[['20', '04', '82', '47', '65']]
3
[['18', '35', '87', '10']]
2
[['17', '47', '82']]
1
[['95', '64']]
0
[['75']]
0

now this is what i want but i cant seem to get this

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand it. What are you trying to do? Are you trying to find sum of each row?

Comment: Could you please 1) keep _one_ question/task/issue per thread, and 2) clarify what your expected output/result is? Seems like you haven't broken down your task.

Comment: @AndrejKesely well i havent completed the sum function because thats simple to do but do u see how in the original string each row increases by 1 right so i want my return_triangle function to convert that string to an array of the time [[1],[2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15].....] etc. But if u look at my output i put to test it my return_triangle function doesn't add the last 2 rows to the array which i don't get how to fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## First:

For me it works if you do the following:

```
def return_triangle(triangle,n):
```

change to:

```
def return_triangle(triangle,rows):
```

Or change the rows in the while loop to n. That's an error that don't even let you run the code so maybe some copy paste error.

## Second:

You have an error in your for loop. I don't know why you do -1 but it should look like this and it works:

```
for i in reversed(range(len(arr_triangle)-1)):
```

to

```
for i in reversed(range(len(arr_triangle))):
```

Don't forget the index starts with 0.

The output would look like this:

```
14
[['04', '62', '98', '27', '23', '09', '70', '98', '73', '93', '38', '53', '60', '04', '23']]
13
[['63', '66', '04', '68', '89', '53', '67', '30', '73', '16', '69', '87', '40', '31']]
12
[['91', '71', '52', '38', '17', '14', '91', '43', '58', '50', '27', '29', '48']]
11
[['70', '11', '33', '28', '77', '73', '17', '78', '39', '68', '17', '57']]
10
[['53', '71', '44', '65', '25', '43', '91', '52', '97', '51', '14']]
9
[['41', '48', '72', '33', '47', '32', '37', '16', '94', '29']]
8
[['41', '41', '26', '56', '83', '40', '80', '70', '33']]
7
[['99', '65', '04', '28', '06', '16', '70', '92']]
6
[['88', '02', '77', '73', '07', '63', '67']]
5
[['19', '01', '23', '75', '03', '34']]
4
[['20', '04', '82', '47', '65']]
3
[['18', '35', '87', '10']]
2
[['17', '47', '82']]
1
[['95', '64']]
0
[['75']]
0  # Output of max_sum
```

Since max_sum is 0 the last 0 is from maxsum the output before is from your for loop.

As a remark you can see that you have [['75']] => a list in a list.

You can eliminate this if you change this:

```
triangle_array.append([temp_arr])
```

to

```
triangle_array.append(temp_arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  listOfStrings = [ i.split() for i in triangle.splitlines() if i ]
  listOfInt = []
  for row in listOfStrings:
      listOfInt.append( [ int(x) for x in row ] )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a more advanced solution as it is a list comprehension within a list comprehension but shows the power of Python when you get up and runnig with it.

Given your definition of name `triangle` above, the following code shows how it can be easily parsed into a list of lists of ints:

```
In [1]: [[int(item) for item in row.strip().split()]
   ...:  for row in triangle.strip().splitlines()]
Out[1]: 
[[75],
 [95, 64],
 [17, 47, 82],
 [18, 35, 87, 10],
 [20, 4, 82, 47, 65],
 [19, 1, 23, 75, 3, 34],
 [88, 2, 77, 73, 7, 63, 67],
 [99, 65, 4, 28, 6, 16, 70, 92],
 [41, 41, 26, 56, 83, 40, 80, 70, 33],
 [41, 48, 72, 33, 47, 32, 37, 16, 94, 29],
 [53, 71, 44, 65, 25, 43, 91, 52, 97, 51, 14],
 [70, 11, 33, 28, 77, 73, 17, 78, 39, 68, 17, 57],
 [91, 71, 52, 38, 17, 14, 91, 43, 58, 50, 27, 29, 48],
 [63, 66, 4, 68, 89, 53, 67, 30, 73, 16, 69, 87, 40, 31],
 [4, 62, 98, 27, 23, 9, 70, 98, 73, 93, 38, 53, 60, 4, 23]]

In [2]:
```

both the uses of, (just), `.strip()` above could be deleted for your example string but I usually use them as it allows for spurious blank lines and spaces at the end, (and beginning), of lines.

## Explanation

The outer loop is the second line of the comprehension which assigns local variable `row` to successive lines of triangle. The inner loop is shown as the first line of the comprehension and produces the inner list by splitting each `row` on whitespace and converting the resultant `item` to an int.

Comment: wow this is a really clean solution i didnt know this! thanks!

Comment: @TalhaAbid: Please upvote if you think it useful :-)